# Reduce the filesize of a PDF with text?

Tags: pdf, compression

I have a PDF created with [PDF Sandwich](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/).  Each page of the PDF contains a background image and some foreground text.

I want to reduce the filesize (not the resolution) of the background image - and preserve the selectable text.

- Using ImageMagick's `convert` reduces the size, but removes the text.
- `ps2pdf` does not significantly reduce the filesize.
- `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen …` reduces the resolution, but doesn't seem to re-compress the images.
- `qpdf --compress-streams=y --recompress-flate --optimize-images in.pdf out.pdf` only makes a minor difference.

If I extract the background images and use `pngquant` or similar, the filesize is cut dramatically. But I have no way to use that new image to replace the old image.

Is there any way to compress the images in a PDF while keeping the text intact?

---

As suggested in the comments, running `pdfimages -list output.pdf`

Gives:

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    3483  4800  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        11  0   300   300 1147K 2.3%
   2     1 image    3483  4800  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        24  0   300   300  397K 0.8%
   3     2 image    3483  4800  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        37  0   300   300 1441K 2.9%
   4     3 image    3483  4800  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        50  0   300   300 1880K 3.8%
   5     4 image    3483  4800  gray    1   8  jpeg   no        63  0   300   300 1050K 6.4%
…
```

Comment: Related maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995195/is-there-a-way-to-convert-images-embed-in-a-pdf-from-jpg-gif-whatever-to-png-or

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `pdfimages -list` (might need to install `poppler-utils` package)

Answer (score 3):

`qpdf` has modes to recompress data streams and especially images within PDFs.

So, something like

```
qpdf --compress-streams=y --recompress-flate --optimize-images in.pdf out.pdf
```

Comment: Sadly that only reduces it by a couple of bytes. It doesn't seem to recompress the images.

Comment: Thanks. That reduced a pdf from 22MB to 2.9MB for me. It seems `--optimize-images` was important in my case. Adding `--compression-level=9 --object-streams=generate` saved only a few more KB.